# How to change screen resolution when Selenium WebDriver running as background process?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

The general structure is Selenium and Jenkins integration.

In Jenkins, I have a Windows slave node, and then build the project in the Jenkins master node, let Selenium in the slave node Windows Server running in the background.

The results showed that after running the case, there are a lot of error, showing elements are not visible, after the screenshot, I found the window is 1024 * 663, not the expected 1920 * 1080, so do not drag the scroll bar, a lot of elements cannot click.

How to modify the window to the maximum?

My Chrome version: 62,
Python version: 3.6,
Selenium: 3.

```
driver.maximize_window ()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

Have tried, no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080, driver.window_handles[0])
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: thank you  very  much，Your answer has solved my problem 。

Comment: @mozi, check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: Works like magic! Thanks. I tried with driver.maximize_window() but it didn't worked.

Comment: What does this code mean? It gives a warning: `UserWarning: Only 'current' window is supported for W3C compatibile browsers.` And it doesn't seem to change the screen siz, it stays 1366x768.

Comment: @Velkan, which browser are you using? Try to update your browser.

Comment: It's Firefox. And I've found the solution for Firefox in headless mode: it's the `MOZ_HEADLESS_WIDTH` and `MOZ_HEADLESS_HEIGHT` environment variables that set the screen size.

Comment: @Velkan, ok, nice!